# how to make a get call with JSON and retrieve data

Tags: php, json

I am trying to follow instructions from an RFC spec to retrieve data from "certificate transparency log" [known logs here](https://sites.google.com/site/certificatetransparency/known-logs)

Instructions say to make a JSON call but i don't seem to be having any success.. i actually don't get any data response at all.

Here is the guide I am trying to follow:
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6962#section-4.6

Here is the php code I am using

```
<?php

$data = array("start" => "1", "end" => "10");                                                                    
$data_string = json_encode($data);                                                                                   
                                                                                                                     
$ch = curl_init('https://ct.googleapis.com/pilot/ct/v1/get-entries');                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))                                                                       
);                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                     
$result = curl_exec($ch);

var_dump(json_decode($result, true));
?>
```

Comment: check url. normal curl response from command line is, `{
  "error_message": "Missing \u0026#39;start\u0026#39; parameter",
  "success": false
}
`

Comment: thx but any idea what that might mean?

Comment: okay, i got it working, the service uses certificates so i had to ignore the verification to get a response. CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false

Answer (score 0):

The service I was connecting to has an SSL certificate installed and was not responding to my requests. Disabling the trust verification was the solution. I added this to the CURL options **CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false**